# MATLABで書かれたデータ分析のプログラムの変形について

Tags: c, array, matlab, 行列

７つのセンサのデータから
外れ値のインデックスを求めるデータ分析用のプログラムをMATLABで書いています。

現在のプログラムを実行すると以下の結果が出力されるのですが、

```
%disp(data)の出力
     1     4     7     4     6     2     6
     2     5     1     4     7     2     6
     3     7     2     5     1    12     7
%disp(medianOfData)の出力
     2     5     2     4     6     2     6
```

これらの出力を以下のようにしたいです。（なお、空白の半角等は考慮しません）

```
%disp(data)の出力

1 2 3 4 5 7 7
1 2 4 4 5 6 7
1 2 2 12 6 6 7

%disp(medianOfData)の出力
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

現在のコードをどのように修正すればいいでしょうか。

実行プログラム

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 2, 12, 6, 6, 7];

num_sensors = 7;
thresh = 5;

data = reshape(data, [], num_sensors);

disp(data)

% 中央値
medianOfData = median(data);
disp(medianOfData)
```

実行環境
Mac OS, MATLAB_R2019a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d=1:21
に対して、

```
reshape(d,[],7)

ans =

     1     4     7    10    13    16    19
     2     5     8    11    14    17    20
     3     6     9    12    15    18    21
```

ではなく

```
ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
    15    16    17    18    19    20    21
```

という形に成形したいと言うことで良いでしょうか。
一度、reshape(d,7,[]) で縦方向にreshapeして

```
reshape(d,7,[]) =

     1     8    15
     2     9    16
     3    10    17
     4    11    18
     5    12    19
     6    13    20
     7    14    21
```

転置するのが一番わかりやすいかなと思います。

```
reshape(d,7,[])'=

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
    15    16    17    18    19    20    21
```

実際のデータだと、こうですね。

```
data = reshape(data, num_sensors, [])'

data =

     1     2     3     4     5     7     7
     1     2     4     4     5     6     7
     1     2     2    12     6     6     7
```